# Faliure of Unequipping Trigger in Roblox

Tags: function, lua, roblox

```
function Part1()
    wait(0)
    script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 32
end

function Part2()
    wait(0)
    script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid.Walkspeed = 16
end

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(Part1)
script.Parent.Unequipped:Connect(Part2)
```

I want to properly trigger the function Part2, which is linked to unequipping function, but it fails. The code is inside the tool I want to use. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does this [Tool have or need a handle](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Tool/RequiresHandle)?

**If your Tool does not need a handle**, you can make the Equipped and Unequipped events
fire without any extra setup by adding this to your LocalScript :

```
script.Parent.RequiresHandle = false
```

**If your Tool does need a handle**, double check that there is a Part that is a child of the Tool named "Handle".

[image: An image of the tool heirarchy. At the top level is the Tool. Inside it is a LocalScript and a Part named Handle.]

Comment: My tool doesn't need, nor uses handle, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the player's `Humanoid` by doing:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer --Gets the player whos client the localscript is running on
local character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait() --The script will likely load into the game and run before the player and its character loads into the game, so we wait for the character to eventually get the humanoid from it
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
```

This is because when the game runs, the tools that are in `StarterPlayer` will clone to the player's Backpack, so you cannot do `script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid`.
Now, we can continue with the original script:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

function Part1()
   humanoid.WalkSpeed = 32
end

function Part2()
   humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
end

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(Part1)
script.Parent.Unequipped:Connect(Part2)
```

Comment: I have tested your approach and it doesn't seem to be working. Does your script work in test mode of roblox studio?

Comment: Can you update your post with the hierarchy of your tool? I think it would be easier to help you then.

Comment: You mean like the whole hirearchy of the tool when you equip and unequip it or only the tool itself?

Comment: Oh wait. If the Part1 function works and Part2 doesn't, then just make sure when you are changing walkspeed in the Part2 function, you refer to it as `WalkSpeed`, not `Walkspeed`; It's case sensitive.